# How to read object of jsonp type

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, wordnik

I got this HTML file to fire a GET request to the random word API (wordnik) server. It returns with something like this:

```
[{"id":2998982,"word":"failproof"}]
```

I only want the `"word"` part but don't know how to access it. I thought it would be `data.word` but it just printed `undefined`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
     <title>Random Word Generator</title>
   </head>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>

   <script>
     function generateRandomWord() {
        var randomWordURL = "http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/words.json/randomWords?hasDictionaryDef=true&minCorpusCount=0&minLength=5&maxLength=15&limit=1&api_key=APIkey";

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: randomWordURL,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          jsonpCallback: 'displayRandomWord'
        });
      }

     function displayRandomWord(data) {
       document.getElementById("randomword").innerHTML=data.word;
     }
   </script>

   <body onload="generateRandomWord()">
     <div id="randomword"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: data is an array, not a plain object

Comment: you probably want `data[0].word`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like data is an array so to access it you should replace `data.word`by `data[0].word`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON example, you have **an array of objects** instead of an object. If your code will always get one element in this array and you want to extract its `word` property, you can change it to:

```
 function displayRandomWord(data) {
   document.getElementById("randomword").innerHTML=data[0].word;
 }
```